# c# Lambda subqueries (linq2sql)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda, subquery

Is it possible to write the equivalent of this TSQL statement in Lambda?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        pba1.adGroupsId
,      Amount = (SELECT pba2.value 
                  FROM   ProjectBudgetAdjustment pba2 
                  WHERE  pba1.budgetId = pba2.budgetId 
                  AND    pba1.adGroupsId = pba2.adGroupsId 
                  AND    pba2.metricId IN 
                  (
                      SELECT  id 
                      FROM    Metrics 
                      WHERE   [description] = 'Amount')
                  )
,      [Hours] = (SELECT pba2.value 
                   FROM   ProjectBudgetAdjustment pba2 
                   WHERE  pba1.budgetId = pba2.budgetId 
                   AND    pba1.adGroupsId = pba2.adGroupsId 
                   AND    pba2.metricId IN 
                  (
                      SELECT id 
                      FROM   Metrics 
                      WHERE  [description] = 'Hours')
                  )
FROM    ProjectBudgetAdjustment pba1
WHERE   pba1.budgetId IN
(
   SELECT  id
   FROM ProjectBudget
   WHERE   projectId IN
   (
      SELECT  id
      FROM    Projects
      WHERE   code = 'xxx'
   )
)
```

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite this query into LINQ-to-SQL/EF, don't forget the possibility to loose performance on your query. But in performance point of view you should redesign your query imho. Just rewrite the where clause into an inner join.

Comment: using linq2sql? linq over poco objects?

Comment: Lambda is returning too many rows, four disciplines each with an amount and hours, so Lambda returns 8 rows. I placed the SQL here as an illustration of how TSQL could deal with it, performance was not in mind. I quess if it is not possible I will need to revisit the db architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be total wrong here, but is it something like :

```
ProjectBudgetAdjustment
.Where( pba => pba.ProductBudget.Products.Code == "xxx")
.Where( pba => (pba.Metrics.Description == "Hours" 
             || pba.Metrics.Description == "Amount"))
.GroupBy(   pba => pba.ProductBudget.adGroupsId )
.Select (
    r => new
    {
        adGroupsId = r.Key,
        Hours  = r.Sum(i=> (i.Metrics.Description == "Hours"  ? i.value : 0m)),
        Amount = r.Sum(i=> (i.Metrics.Description == "Amount" ? i.value : 0m))
    }
);
```

Comment: The above lambda is correct except that now I have to deal with enumerating an anonymous typed object

Comment: Doesn't have to be anonymous. If you have a suitable class, say ProjectSummary, then you change the expression to be  ... .Select(r => new ProjectSummary {  adGroupsId = r.Key, ....

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I have had a disruptive week, what with national holidays and civil unrest, but now have had time in the office to address, thanks.